# Deep neural network should hidden nodes increase, decrease, or stay the same

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Should hidden node numbers in hidden layers generally increase, decrease, or stay the same. I see in some conv nets like alexnet, VGG, and resnet the number of nodes tends to increase in subsequent layers. Why is this and does it really matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general rule, it is fully problem dependent issue of how to construct your neural network. Nearly any scheme - decreasing, increasing, small bottle neck, wide "neck" - has its own applications. In order to really understand what is happening you need lots of experience, but in general tuning architectures is quite tricky and usually done with some "rule of the thumb" like "we use architecture used by XXX, and then try to tune it a bit".